# Merthen's third theorem and uncertainty of prime hits

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, euler-product

Conjecture(1)

Merten's third theorem says:

$$\lim_{L\to\infty}\ln L\prod_{p\le L}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=e^{-\gamma}$$

we have a wild discussion here around the table whether it is possible to deduct from this theorem that:

over an $L\in \Bbb N$ the probability $\Psi(x)$ to hit the next integer to $x\in \Bbb R$ which is not divisible by primes $p\le L$, would be decreasing when $x$ increasing according to

$$\Psi(x) \sim \frac {e^{\gamma}\ln L}{\ln x}$$

We can not find a consensus. May we get your help. Is this correct? Why, what is the formal relation?

(1) Conjecture to be cited Vaseghi 2013

Comment: Typo: You need to replace $L$ by $n$ (or vice versa).

Comment: You still have an $n$ in $\lim_{n\to\infty}$.

Comment: I can't understand the conjecture as written.